# Extracting Coefficient Values from Several Regressions and Storing in New Matrix

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, statistics

I have run a series of 86 regressions (numbered 83-168) and stored them as "reg_83", "reg_84", et cetera. I am now trying to extract the coefficient values for each variable and input them into a new dataframe for analysis to see how the coefficient values change over time. I have a new matrix ("gencoef") with 12 columns and 86 rows. I have a column dedicated to each independent variable. I am trying to run a loop which will store the coefficient value from each regression in the appropriate cell in the variable's column. I have used the following code but to no avail. I am not particularly skilled at loops so it might be a relatively straight-forward solution:

```
for(i in c(83:168)){
  for(j in c(1:86)){
   eval(parse(text=paste(
"gencoef[",j,",2] <- summary(reg_",i,")$coefficients[1,1]"),sep==""))
}
}
```

For whatever reason it is currently creating a space between "reg_" and the number, so it seems to think I am running "reg_ 83" which of course does not work. However, I have a `sep==""` command in the loop, so I do not understand where the issue is coming from. Perhaps someone can enlighten me?

Comment: This is a job for [broom](https://broom.tidyverse.org/) and [purrr](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/), not `for` loops and `eval(parse(...))`

Comment: You need `sep = ""` to have no space in your `paste` (not `==`). But I agree with alistaire, use `broom` to do this all at once with `tidy`

Comment: First, easier to store all the regressions in a list. To answer your question, you can use `sapply` on the `list` and use `coef(list[[regression_number]])` instead of going the `summary$coefficients` way.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways of doing this but here is one I came up with very quickly. It uses the `broom` package as commented above.

First let's make a list of models:

```
# make a response variable and a matrix of predictors
set.seed(111)
response <- rnorm(10)
predictors <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10)

# model response using each predictor to give a list of 10 model outputs
mods <- apply(predictors, 2, function(x) lm(response ~ x))
```

Now to tidy up the output with broom and bind together the resulting data frames.

```
library(broom)
l <- lapply(mods, tidy)
do.call(rbind, l)
```

Or using `purrr` you can eliminate both `lapply` and `do.call`.

```
library(purrr)
map_df(mods, tidy)
```

Gives the same result.

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
#   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
# * <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 (Intercept)  0.0643      0.564    0.114   0.912 
# 2 x            0.0851      0.454    0.187   0.856 
# 3 (Intercept)  0.0256      0.511    0.0501  0.961 
# 4 x           -0.0763      0.567   -0.135   0.896 
# 5 (Intercept)  0.113       0.514    0.220   0.832 
# 6 x           -0.310       0.458   -0.677   0.518 
# 7 (Intercept) -0.448       0.562   -0.797   0.448 
# etc
```

Oh, and you could give each model an `.id`:

```
map_dfr(mods, tidy, .id = "model")

# A tibble: 20 x 6
#   model term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#   <chr> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 1     (Intercept) -0.672       0.263   -2.56    0.0338
# 2 1     x           -0.0655      0.284   -0.230   0.824 
# 3 2     (Intercept) -0.688       0.260   -2.65    0.0293
# 4 2     x            0.133       0.225    0.589   0.572 
# etc
```